# Is glycinate ligand a monoanion or a zwitterion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, amino-acids

Glycinate as far as I can guess from the structure is a monoanion with negative charge on oxygen atom (though that negative charge is resonating). But when I used this logic in my exam it costed me 4 marks. I don't understand why.

Is it because it is derived from glycine in strongly basic medium which is not a monoanion but a zwitterion? Still, it doesn't seem to be making sense.

Comment: Solid glycine is in zwitterionic form. That's why it is hard to dissolve. That's probably what the question asked. Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solutions more basic than pH 9.6 glycine mainly exists as the carboxylate anion you describe. Between 9.6 and 2.34 it exists mainly in the zwitterion form.

[image: titration curve]

titration curve from [here](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-titration-curve-of-glycine)

Comment: So, what exactly do I consider glycinate ligand to be-mono anion or zwitterion,  from an exam point of view ?

Comment: It entirely depends on the pH of the solution it is in. What exactly does the question say?

Comment: You may find more info [here](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp0457592).

Answer (score 2):

,Assuming glycinate is in its anionic form ($\ce{H2N-CH2-CO2^-}$), one thing to consider is it may not act just as a simple anionic ligand like chloride or hydroxide.  You can count off four atoms from the nitrogen to either carboxyl-ate  oxygen and those atoms both have available electron pairs.  So you add the metal atom and you get a five-membered ring similar to that formed with ethylenediamine.  Thus, **glycinate anion may act as a chelating agent.**

Comment: An example of this is ferrous glycinate  http://ve.scielo.org/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0004-06222001000500003